# Website returns error 404 with content

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I switched to a new webhosting recently and found an unusual error - all pages except root on my website are returning 404 error, but with actual html of the page.

As an example, I can give this page:

```
http://www.mm-vet.cz/cenik
```

It returns 404 error but with actual page html(so you can see it in browser).

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^cat
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

**Why is the server returning 404 error when my page actually exists and how can I fix it?**

Comment: which php framework you are using?

Comment: not really any for this web

Comment: remove this line `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]`

Comment: There isnt such a line

Comment: sorry this line `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]`

Comment: it's hard to debug. so it's better to remove every think from .htaccess, then  add one by one. Actually if you don't use php MVC framework then .htaccess is not mandatory.

Comment: But I want to use nice URLs on my site for SEO.

Comment: From what I understand `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^cat` means the following rule will only be used if the query string is not `cat`.

Comment: well the point of my .htaccess is to rewrite http://www.mm-vet.cz/page to http://www.mm-vet.cz/index.php?cat=page
It seemed to work, but I can switch it to whatever else if it does the job

Comment: if you propose what my .htaccess should look like to rewrite http://www.mm-vet.cz/page to http://www.mm-vet.cz/index.php?cat=page I can change it that way if it helps you with debugging this problem

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you are targeting a set of extensions? Can this work by using a simpler rule to check whether the requested file exists and, if not, then performs the rewrite?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Does your PHP code, at any point, send a `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found')`? Is that being invoked?

I have never experienced a webhost sending 404 errors, but also sending the requested content.